# Replace all lines in vim with whatever is after the last slash on a line

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have sample data like:

```
aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/fff
aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/fff/gg
aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/fff/gg/hhhhh
```

How can I parse out only:

```
fff
gg
hhhhh
```

with vim or bash?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk`. You want last field but you have different delimiter.

-F : --field-separator.

Awk NF gives you the total number of fields in a record So when I say NF, it hold the last field number or its index. so {print $NF} is similar to { print $1} or {print $2}.

```
➜  awk -F'/' '{print $NF}' test.txt
fff
gg
hhhhh
```

Answer (score 0):

With Vim you can use the following to remove everything before the last slash (`/`):

```
:%s/.*\///
```

You could do something similar with `sed`:

```
sed 's/.*\///' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash is probably not the first choice for this:

```bsh
mapfile -t < data; printf %s\\n "${MAPFILE[@]##*/}"
```